# WCF Exception Handling proxy

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client

I am using the ErrorHandlingProxy from 
[here](http://wcfproxygenerator.codeplex.com/)
and had a coupla questions. 
I noticed that the ExceptionHandlingProxyBase executes all calls in the main thread. What do I need to do to initialize and run in the background? I am using it like in the examples in form load

```
private MyServiceProxy _proxy = null;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _proxy = new MyServiceProxy("MyBinding");
}
```

Also if possible,I would to generate it without adding a service reference, does anyone know what switches I can use and call svcutil manually?

Regards

_Eric

Comment: ok, I'm an idiot, forgot bout just wrappin' the _proxy.mymethod in a background worker. So only the 2nd question applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be unable to do @ this time.
[link text](http://wcfproxygenerator.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=83595)

Answer (score 0):

To get the switches for svcutil just type:

```
svcutil /?
```

However, we have found that it is better to build the proxy classes from scratch, see:

http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122

Note this only works if you have control of both the client and the server.

Comment: thanks for the link, @switches I knew that, but was not sure what switches to add to have it generate the errorhandlingProxy also. Before I would use the /r /ct /out /n, but this will not generate the additional proxy like add service reference does